# Adjust spacing between R Shiny's renderText elements

Tags: css, r, shiny

How do I adjust the spacing between the end of the table and the sentence, "Place very close to table".

Here is the default spacing:
[image]

Here is the desired spacing:
[image]

```
R Script
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
    dashboardSidebar(width = 0),

    body <- dashboardBody(
      fluidRow(
        tabBox(
          id = "tabset1", height = "250px",
          tabPanel("Tab1", "First tab content"),
          tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2")
        ),
       
      ),
      fluidRow(htmlOutput("last_updated"))
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    # The currently selected tab from the first box
    output$tabset1Selected <- renderText({
      input$tabset1
    })
    
    output$last_updated <- renderText({
      paste("<font size='1px;'>&ensp;&ensp;Place very close to table</font>") 
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibility:

```
body <- dashboardBody(
  div(
    style = "display: flex; flex-direction: column;",
    tabBox(
      id = "tabset1", height = "250px",
      tabPanel("Tab1", "First tab content"),
      tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2")
    ),
    div(style = "margin-top: -20px;"),
    htmlOutput("last_updated")
  )
)
```

Comment: I've always used fluidPage to layout a Shiny page. Is your answer using "flex" instead of fluidPage to impose a layout? Are there general rules of when you would use fluidPage and when you would use Flex?

Comment: @ixodid You mean *fluidRow*? A `fluidRow` is just a `div` with a certain class, intended to contain some `column` elements. Here I use a flexbox in column direction to impose the stacking. I firstly thought that the flexbox were not necessary because HTML elements are stacked "by default", but for some reason (surely a CSS property of `tabBox`) this is not the case here.